# How to create tracker object in java with opencv as we create in python or c++

Tags: java, opencv

How do I create a tracker object in Java with OpenCV as we would create in Python or C++?

```
tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN']

tracker_type = tracker_types[4]

if tracker_type == tracker_types[0]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[1]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[2]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[3]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[4]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[5]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
```

Comment: There's no classes in Java with `tracker` in the name that I can find---it may not exist. You can see the list of all classes [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/).

Comment: Thank you .Is there any module for object tracking in java that i can use.

Comment: Not sure, sorry; I don't use Java for OpenCV. There are of course the manual methods; tracking by color, or by SIFT/SURF/ORB/etc, background subtraction, really depends on your problem.